# HTML / CSS Image thumbnail roll over

Tags: html, css, rollover

I asked a question on here yesterday for this solution, and thought I had solved it and marked an answer as correct but now I realise it wasn't quite right.

I've been playing around with a fiddle, essentially I want this..

[image: Rollover]

On the left would be the NON hovered state, then ON HOVER I would like the blue overlay and the text 'View Project'.

Here is the fiddle I am playing with, the only thing I cannot get to show is the text.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Db9n/11/)

```
<div class="cont">

<div class="work-thumb"><img src="http://www.menshealth.co.uk/cm/menshealthuk/images/qQ/mh-face-off-winner-MED-07032011.jpg" /><a class="roll-text">View</a></div>
```

A few things to note... the `<img>` MUST be responsive. so the 'view project' must also be responsive ( cannot use fixed pixel widths for it ).

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate the text when hovering on the `div` element, not the anchor itself:

```
.work-thumb:hover a.roll-text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Please see the [**updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Db9n/12/).

Comment: Clean solution but it is not responsive is it?

Comment: Yes, it is. The `top` and `left` properties are relative to the containing element.

Comment: Replace "View" with a sentence and resize the result window. The text won't wrap.

Comment: I doubt it's a problem, since nowhere did the OP mention sentences being inside the link? Also, he said `img` must be responsive, not the text inside it...

Comment: I guess you are right - I just saw his example with "View Project" and read "responsive" and thought this should wrap on smaller screens.

Comment: Doh! Make's so much sense now I see where I was going wrong, obviously I couldn't `:hover` a hidden element, which is why it didn't show. Thank's a lot Ben - Marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sibling selector `+` to show the text because it is hidden.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Db9n/13/)</kbd>

```
.work-thumb img:hover + .roll-text {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Not what he wanted - see the question, and more specifically the example.